# Calculating $P(B^{c}|A^{c})$

Tags: probability

I was given the following question (here I give only the setting):

> A box has $10$ red balls and $5$ black balls. A ball is selected from
>   the box. If the ball is red, it is returned to the box. If the ball is
>   black, it is returned to the box along with two additional black
>   balls. After this, another ball is drawn.

To solve one of parts in the question I wish to calculate $P(B^{c}|A^{c})$
where $A$ as the event that the first ball drawn is Red, $B$ as
the event that second ball drawn is Red and given that I calculated
$$P(A)=\frac{2}{3},P(B)=\frac{98}{153},P(B|A^{c})=\frac{10}{17}$$

Given that $A^{c}$ occurs I have it that before the second draw there
are $7$ Blcak balls and $10$ Red balls so the probability of drawing
a black ball is $\frac{7}{17}=1-P(B|A^{c})$.

But if $$P(B^{c}|A^{c})=1-P(B|A^{c})$$ then $$P(B^{c}|A^{c})+P(B|A^{c})=1$$

But $A^{c}$ may not occur so I believe that the last equality is
false.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re doing nothing wrong in the calculations; your error is in thinking that $$P(B^{c}\mid A^{c})+P(B\mid A^{c})=1\tag{1}$$ is contradicted by the fact that $A^c$ may not occur. $P(B^c\mid A^c)$ is the probability of $B^c$ **given that** $A^c$ occurs, and $P(B\mid A^c)$ is the probability of $B$ **given that** $A^c$ occurs. If you know that $A^c$ has occurred, then indeed it is true that either $B^c$ or $B$ must occur, which is exactly what $(1)$ says.

Now if you had somehow arrived at the equation $$P(B^c\text{ and }A^c)+P(B\text{ and }A^c)=1\;,\tag{2}$$

then you’d be right to be concerned, and for exactly the reason that you gave: $A^c$ may not occur. But $P(B\text{ and }A^c)$ is different from $P(B\mid A^c)$; in fact, $P(B\text{ and }A^c)=P(B\mid A^c)P(A^c)$.

Comment: @Belgi: You’re welcome!